# To find the limit of a function of two variables using $\epsilon -\delta$ method

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I was trying to prove that the limit of the function $\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ is 1 as we apply the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$. I took the polar form for the variables $x$ and $y$ and then applied the limit $r\rightarrow 0$ and finally answer is $1$. But I am unable to prove the same with the help of $\epsilon -\delta$ method. Can anyone help me in solving the same. Following is my attempt. Please feel free to rectify the proof.

[image]

Comment: Please use Mathjax...

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin'(0) = 1$: $$\sin(\theta) = \theta + r(\theta)$$ where $\frac{r(\theta)}{\theta} \to 0$ as $\theta \to 0$.

Comment: I am unable to get the term $sin \theta = \theta + r(\theta)$ here. Could you please explain

Comment: sin(theta)/theta = 1 + r(theta)/theta, now if theta tends to zero sin theta/ theta tends to 1 that is true. That is what written there. $r$ and theta are polar form notation.  To prove this use $x = r cos theta$ , $y = r sin theta$ then (x, y) tends to (0, 0) will reduce to (r, theta) tends to (0, 0)